# Conversion problem from Image to base64 using C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I am facing strange problem while converting Image to base64, some specific image which is on png format is not getting the base64 string when I copy paste those string on url so it is not displaying any image, but when I use Online Image to base64 website so it gave me true base64 string which is also open on browser.

```
 var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", ProperteaseAPI.Helpers.Common.ImgToBase64(img.ItemFileName));

 html += "<img style ='width:50px; height: 50px; margin: 5px; src='" + imgSrc + "' />";'

public static string ImgToBase64(string path)
    {
        try
        {
        var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        string baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];
        string PDF_Path = context.Server.MapPath("/");
        var FullPath = PDF_Path + path;
        using (Image image = Image.FromFile(FullPath))
        {
            using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

                // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                return base64String;
            }
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you paste a base64-encoded PNG image into a URL that specifies `image/jpeg` as the image type, how would it ever work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. What exactly does "true base64", "paste string on URL" or "online image to base64 website" mean? Show exactly what you're getting and what's the expected value, please. And how you're validating the result.

Comment: Example code https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Convert-Image-file-to-Base64-Encoded-string-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: When using a memory array make sure you set the position to zero after writing.  If you don't you are end the end of the stream and you will not read any data.

Comment: @jdweng - `ToArray` on a `MemoryStream` in no way depends on the current position.

Comment: Show exactly what you're getting and what's the expected value, please